Change BackgroundColor of CollectionView items when PointerOver and Selected
I'm creating a simple ProductManager to learn .NET MAUI.
In dark mode, items in the CollectionView have a clear background color when the pointer hovers over them and when they are selected, as shown in the image below:

Background color in dark theme




However, in light mode, the background color doesn’t appear clear enough for me. So, I’d like to change it. According to CollectionView#Change Selected Item Color, I used this code to adjust it (I'm very sorry about this! Due to some formatting issues, StackOverflow marked my XAML code below as incorrect, so I had to use blockquotes to display it):
> <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
>     <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
>         <VisualState Name="Normal" />
>         <VisualState Name="PointerOver">
>             <VisualState.Setters>
>                 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
>             </VisualState.Setters>
>         </VisualState>
>         <VisualState Name="Selected">
>             <VisualState.Setters>
>                 <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
>             </VisualState.Setters>
>         </VisualState>
>     </VisualStateGroup>
> </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

After this, when I hover over an item, it turns LightGray. When I click to select it, the background changes to blue. However, when I move the pointer outside the item, it reverts to the default selected background color.

PointerOver





Selected and pointer is still hovering





Pointer goes outside selected item




Is this an issue with my code or .NET MAUI does not support yet?
I want to set custom background colors for the PointerOver and Selected states in VisualState.

The selection effect doesn't last forever. If you select Next or click somewhere else, the effect disappears.

You can use the click method to change the color if you want to change the background color.

I declare a custom ContentView with IsSelected and IsPointerOver properties, e.g.
// CustomView.cs
namespace MauiStatesDemo;
public partial class CustomView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsPointerOverProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsPointerOver), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomView), false);
    public bool IsPointerOver
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPointerOverProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsPointerOverProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsSelectedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsSelected), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomView), false);
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);
    }
}

Next, I use this component and populate IsSelected and IsPointerOver differently. I populate IsSelected by comparing the current item with CollectionView.SelectedItem. I populate IsPointerOver using the VisualStateManager.
Then, I can use IsSelected and IsPointerOver in DataTriggers to control the BackgroundColor. If necessary, I can use a MultiBinding to combine these properties.
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiStatesDemo.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiStatesDemo"
    x:Name="page">
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding SampleData}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SampleData">
                <local:CustomView
                    x:Name="customView"
                    Padding="10,10,10,10"
                    BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=Black}"
                    IsSelected="{MultiBinding {Binding Id},
                                              {Binding SelectedItem.Id, Source={Reference collectionView}},
                                              Converter={local:MultiEqualsConverter}}">
                    <local:CustomView.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Source={Reference customView}}"
                            TargetType="local:CustomView"
                            Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=LightSkyBlue, Dark=Blue}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{MultiBinding {Binding IsPointerOver, Source={Reference customView}},
                                                   {Binding IsSelected, Source={Reference customView}},
                                                   StringFormat='X-{0}-{1}'}"
                            TargetType="local:CustomView"
                            Value="X-True-False">
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light=LightGray, Dark=Gray}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </local:CustomView.Triggers>
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="PRICE" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="AMOUNT" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="4" Text="TOTAL" />
                    </Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="IsPointerOver" Value="True" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </local:CustomView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>

// MainPage.xaml.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
namespace MauiStatesDemo;
public class SampleData
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Name";
}
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<SampleData> SampleData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SampleData>
    {
        new SampleData() { Id = 101, Name="Apples" },
        new SampleData() { Id = 102, Name="Oranges" },
        new SampleData() { Id = 103, Name="Bananas" }
    };
    private SampleData? _selectedData = null;
    public SampleData? SelectedData
    {
        get => _selectedData;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedData != value)
            {
                _selectedData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}

You see for the calculation of IsSelected I needed an MultiEqualsConverter:
// MultiEqualsConverter.cs
using System.Globalization;
namespace MauiStatesDemo;
public class MultiEqualsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public static bool IsEqual(object? a, object? b) => a is null ? b is null : b is not null && a.Equals(b);
    public object Convert(object?[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length < 2) return true;
        for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            if (!IsEqual(values[0], values[i])) return false;
        return true;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();
}


